# password_verify function is getting true after 8 correct digit password and ignoring other wrong digits

Tags: php, passwords, verification, crypt

The function I used to encrypt the password:

```
$password = crypt($password,"$2sd\$qwsazxcdrgfggfdfsdsd");
```

password verify function to match password:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    if($row["email"] === $username && password_verify($password,$row["password"])){
        $message .= "Logging Success!";

        $userFound = true;
        $_SESSION["email"]=$row["email"];
        $_SESSION["fullname"] = $row["full_name"];
        header('Location: view_contact.php');
        exit;
    }else{
        $userFound = false;
    }
}
```

Problem here is, when I enter password. I can login through only entering 8 correct digit passwords and other digits are ignored.

Comment: use the password_hash() function instead of crypt

Comment: @OGenthe password_verify() is part of PHP but the questioner is hashing passwords and checking them incorrectly.

Comment: @Juned Thanks for clearing that up. I have removed my ridiculous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)
```

instead of `crypt`

Comment: This worked like a charm. I used this statement: 
    $password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);   One more thing to ask whether it is an effective way in terms of security.

Comment: `password_hash ` and `password_verify` are secure and a best practice for PHP.

Answer (score -1):

If you use just crypt() then you select the obsolete 56 bit DES based algorithm which indeed only looks at the first 8 characters.

Use "$5$...." or "$6$..." as Salt to select the 256 or 512 bit SHA2 based algorithms.

See "man 3 crypt" under Linux or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_(C) or http://php.net/manual/de/function.crypt.php